# How to select * from table and group by a single column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to select * from several tables but eliminate duplicates without writing out all column names. There are approximately 30 columns from combined tables and I don't want to write each one out.

I know I could write out all column names, but I want to see if there is a way to do it with select *

```
SELECT
        a.* 

FROM "T1"."T2"."T3" a

LEFT JOIN "T1"."T2"."T4" b on b.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN "T1"."T2"."T5" c on c.id = a.id
LEFT JOIN "T1"."T2"."T6" d on d.id = a.id

WHERE a.org = '123' AND kind = 'abc'
```

Is there a way to group by a.id without having to write out every column name? There are 41 columns in the final table as is, and I am trying to only return distinct rows on id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly `group by`, but `row_number()`:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM (SELECT a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.id ORDER BY a.id) as seqnum
      FROM "T1"."T2"."T3" a LEFT JOIN
           "T1"."T2"."T4" b 
           ON b.id = a.id LEFT JOIN
           "T1"."T2"."T5" c
           ON c.id = a.id LEFT JOIN
           "T1"."T2"."T6" d 
           ON d.id = a.id
      WHERE a.org = '123' AND kind = 'abc' 
     ) a
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much, success! I am brand new to SQL, would you mind explaining to me how this works? ROW_NUMBER() etc. is essentially assigning a number to each row for duplicate entry, and then WHERE seqnum = 1 is telling it to only pull the first row of the duplicate entries?

Comment: @Julie . . .Yes, you have that right. `ROW_NUMBER()` provides an enumeration.  The `PARTITION BY` says to restart the ordering for each value there.  The `ORDER BY` provides the ordering.  In this case, no real ordering is provided.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help and explain :)